# Is $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin^2 x }{x^2}dx$ equal to $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin x }{x}dx$?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I saw this in a solution to a problem and can't see why this would be the case. Tried substition and other techniques.

Comment: It can be a simple coincidence. Does this appear as a step in a proof ? Provide more context.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\sin^{2}x}{x^{2}}dx = \left[\sin^{2}x\left(-\frac{1}{x}\right)\right]^{\infty}_{-\infty} - \int_{\mathbb{R}} 2\sin x\cos x \left(-\frac{1}{x}\right)dx \\
=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\sin 2x}{x}dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\sin y}{y}dy
$$
Here we use integration by parts and the substitution $y = 2x$.